# I don't know how to print a sentence only under certain circumstances

Tags: c, string, loops, if-statement

I am blocked at solving  a problem in the book.

The problem is:

> read a word and output the string backwards, and output it backwards,
>   you should print the palindrome if it is the same as the original.
>
> Also, do not use a library such as string.h, but include stdio.h
>   only.

So I created the code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[128];
    char temp;
    int leng = 0;
    char a;

    scanf("%s", str);
    {
        a = str;
    }
    while(str[leng] != '\0')
        leng++;

    for (int i = 0; i < leng/2; i++)
    {
      temp = str[i];
      str[i] = str[leng - i - 1];
      str[leng - i - 1] = temp;
    }
    printf("%s\n", str);
    {
        if (a == str)
            printf("palindrome\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output in reverse order was easily solved, but I blocked in the process at printing palindrome. I tried to print the palindrome only when the input and output values ​​are the same.

However, if (a == str) I used was a code to compare address values.
Also,I thought that it would be useful to implement strcmp as a loop, but I can not find a way to compare the input value with the output value using strcmp.

Is there a way to compare the input and output values ​​in C? Or is there a way to make palindrome print only under certain circumstances (input = output)?

I am wondering if I can code the input value = output value in C exactly.

Note that my code prints the palindrome when the address values ​​are the same. So I haven't seen yet :(

Comment: You need to separate the test for 'is palindrome' from 'print reversed string'.  One way of testing for 'palindromicity' is to make a copy of the string in reverse and then see if the copy is the same as the original.  Another way is to compare the first and last characters — if they're the same, then the second and second from last characters, etc, until you reach the middle.  You can then print the original and the reverse (or print the original twice since you now know that it is the same as the reverse).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a loosely written untested code that should resolve your issues.

```
char str[128];

if( fgets( str, 128, stdin ) )
{
   /* I hate this but restriction on string.h 
      Calculate the size of this string */

   size_t s_len = 0;
   char *p = str;   
   for( ; *p && *p != '\n' ; p++ )
      s_len++;

   /* trim down nextLine characters */      
   if( p && *p == '\n' ) 
   {
      *p = '\0';
   }

   if( s_len == 0 )
   { 
        /* Should never be the case here */
        exit(0);
   }

   /* This should handle both cases of reversing and pallindrom */
   int isPallindrom = 1; /* Lets Say Yes for now*/
   for( size_t i = 0, j = s_len-1; i < j ; i ++, j -- )
   {
        if( str[i] != str[j] )
           isPallindrom = 0; // Not a pallindrom

        swap( str, i, j); // Write a swap function here
   } 

   /* at this point you should have 
      1. a reversed string in a
      2. based on isPallindrom value a confirmation if it really a pallindrom */
}
```

There are some fundamental errors in your code for instance

```
 a = str; 

if (a == str)
```

turn on warnings while compilation to catch these well before execution.

edit - `swap` for you.

```
void swap( char *s, size_t i, size_t j )
{ 
    char t = s[i];
       s[i] = s[j];
       s[j] = t;
}
```

Comment: Woww thanks I've initialized j to s_len another blunder ? May be that's okay here

Comment: Yes `j` should probably start with `s_len -1 `. My scanner stopped at the previous mistake .. ;) This change would require testing `s_len > 0` as well.

Comment: Saying this: Make `i` and `j` be `size_t` as well.

Comment: ... and then inside `swap()` also.

Comment: Also handling of the  `\n` which might have been returned by `fgets()`  seems inconsistent. If around `s_len` is off by one, isn't it?

Comment: `s_len == 0` is (should be?) the trivial case of the user just hitting enter.

Comment: Blank lines; was even thinking the string needs at least 2 characters for input to be called proper acceptable inout

Comment: I'd replaced the whole upper half handling `fgets()`'s input by `str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0'; s_len = strlen(str);` :-) Yes, I am lazy. But libc is fast.

Comment: Still look at the corner case of `str`  just carrying a `'\n'`... the code does one `s_len--;`  to much. While trimming ... does this always, but the corner case it simple.

Comment: I think the code was unnecessarily decreasing s_len while trimming '\n', which was never counted in for loop above so s_len-- in the trimming logic was unnecessary and error prone

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
int compare(char *str1, char *str2)
{
    while(*str1 && *str2){
        if(*str1 ==  *str2){
            str1++;
            str2++;
        }
        else return (*str2 - *str1);
    }
    if(*str1)
        return -1;
    if(*str2)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Logic:

Until '\0' is encountered in one of the strings, check the character in either string. If the characters are equal, continue. Otherwise, return a negative number of the character in string1 > string2, or a positive number if the character in string1 < string2.

Once a '\0' is encountered, check if string1 has any more characters. If yes, it is the greater string, hence return a negative number.
If string1 doesn't have any more characters, check string2. If that too has no more characters, return 0. Otherwise return a positive number.